# What is the difference between web.xml and application.xml?

Tags: java, web-applications

What is the difference between web.xml and application.xml file? What is the purpose of these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

web.xml contains/describes the web application. Its required as part of the .war. The application.xml only come into play if you deploy a Java EE application where multiple wars and ejb etc.